# Slow tiles generation for leaflet js

Tags: python, gdal, tiles, leaflet

I am currently trying to use [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) to display images (jpeg or png) instead of maps, I have followed the instructions on [this blog post](http://build-failed.blogspot.com/2012/11/zoomable-image-with-leaflet.html) to create the tiles using gdal2tiles.py here is the code we used

```
gdal2tile.py -p raster -z 0-5 -w none "SOURCE_PATH.png" "DESTINATION_FOLDER"
```

The command produces the necessary tiles for leaflet, but the problem is that it takes around 2 minutes to create tiles for the attached image (size: 777KB, resolution: 2592x1728) and a disastrous number of tiles of around 1600 file.

I am trying to optimize the time and number of files to generate tiles for leaflet and looking for suggestions, please help.

Comment: If your image is only 777KB, can't you just load it straight into Leaflet? Check this out: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#imageoverlay

Answer (score 1):

you could use [TileMill](http://mapbox.com/tilemill/) to generate the tiles, this outputs all the tiles into one file, in a format called [mbtiles](http://mapbox.com/developers/mbtiles/), that's easier to use, the downside is that you can't just drop the folder onto a web server, but there are quite a few programs that can deal with the file as its just sqlite3.

You could also look at [huge pic](http://hugepic.io/) which seems to be doing something similar to what you are trying.